# QTimer to process large array

Tags: qt, qtimer

I've been trying to use QThread in my [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504282/qprogressbar-update-in-qthread-quitting-crashes) to process large data.  It works but its not perfect and crashes my app at its current version on the link.  Ive read somewhere (cant find the link) to use QTimer and signal and slots instead.

What I would like to do is be able to loop through:

```
connect(this, &UsersProcess::ProgressBarSetValue, this->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setValue);

...
int maxRows = this->listUsers->size();
for(auto iter = this->listUsers->begin(); iter != this->listUsers->end(); ++iter)
{
     row++;
     emit this->ProgressBarSetValue(row);
}
```

where the signal ProgressBarSetValue updates the QProgressBar value.  What I'm not sure what to do is put it in a QTimer so that it doesnt cause the MainWindow to be unusable until the loop ends.

Wondering if anyone can give me an idea or article on how to do this.  Or if there other alternatives without using QThread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT Progress bar showing status of a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551978/qt-progress-bar-showing-status-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Look on QtConcurrent lib. QtConcurrent::run may help for you.

Example.
 At userprocess.h:

```
class UserProcess : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
..............
    void setValue(int Value);

signals:
    void ProgreeBarSetValue(int Value);

private:
    Ui::UserProcess *ui;
    QStringList _data;
};
```

At .cpp you define this function:

```
void doWork(UserProcess* process, const QStringList &list)
{
    static int row = 0;
    for(auto iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        ++row;
        process->setValue(row);
        QThread::msleep(1); //just slows up this function
    }
}
```

Then you make you connection with Qt:QueuedConnection flag:

```
connect(this, &UserProcess::ProgreeBarSetValue, ui->progressBar, &QProgressBar::setValue, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Add some random data to our list

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        _data.append(QString::number(i));

ui->progressBar->setMaximum(1000);
```

And this

```
void UserProcess::setValue(int Value)
{
    emit ProgreeBarSetValue(Value);
}
```

Start our hard function

```
QtConcurrent::run(doWork, this, _data);
```

Also dont forget add this at .pro file

```
QT +=  concurrent
```